# How to connect to a Google Cloud SQL database from Metabase (when Metabase is running on Google Cloud Run)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, metabase

I am running [Metabase](https://www.metabase.com/) on Google Cloud Run and am trying to connect to a MySQL database instance (which also resides in Google Cloud SQL, in the same project).

NB. This is not Metabase's application database, but rather connecting a database to perform analysis on the data as per https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/setting-up-metabase.html

- When I run Metabase locally, I can connect fine using the Public IP (once my IP was whitelisted)
- I cannot connect via Metabase on Cloud Run.
- I have added the database to `Cloud SQL connections` within Cloud Run (per: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run)
- The database I'm trying to connect to is a [Read Replica](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/create-replica) (if that makes any difference)
- When I 'allow all' on the Cloud SQL instance using `0.0.0.0/0` I am able to connect using the Public IP. Once I remove this rule I cannot connect.
- I understand Cloud Run does not yet support Cloud SQL Private IPs

For connecting to the database I am constrained to using Metabase's web interface:

[image]

Within this interface I have tried:

- Setting Host to the public IP
- Setting the `Additional JDBC connection string options` to `cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory` as per https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory (with `<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>` replaced with the real name)

  - When I set this the error is: `Could not connect to address=(host=<HOST>)(port=3306)(type=master) : Socket fail to connect to host:<HOST>, port:3306. Socket factory failed to initialized with option "socketFactory" set to "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory"` (I have redacted the real `<HOST>` value)

Thoughts:

- From what I now understand, when I set socketFactory in `Additional JDBC connection string options` the host is ignored.
- I can only assume I have not properly formatted or configured the `Additional JDBC connection string options` field

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had added a connection to the application database, but not to the new database I wanted to connect. However, now having also added that, I am hitting the same issue.

Comment: It's not Cloud Run, but I've managed to deploy to App Engine and connect Metabase to Cloud SQL-hosted DBs by allowing for connections (network settings on the DBs) from the Metabase app service. You also need to ensure that the App Engine service account has permissions for Cloud SQL (quick and easy is to give it the `Cloud SQL Client` role).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to CloudSQL thorugh any TCP connections as it is stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run):

> Cloud Run (fully managed) does not support connecting to the Cloud SQL instance using TCP. Your code should not try to access the instance using an IP address such as 127.0.0.1 or 172.17.0.1.

You can connect to the CloudSQL instance, using the instance connection name using a code similar to this:

```
// The configuration object specifies behaviors for the connection pool.
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

// Configure which instance and what database user to connect with.
config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", DB_NAME));
config.setUsername(DB_USER); // e.g. "root", "postgres"
config.setPassword(DB_PASS); // e.g. "my-password"

// For Java users, the Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory can provide authenticated connections.
// See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory for details.
config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME);
config.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", "false");

// ... Specify additional connection properties here.
// ...

// Initialize the connection pool using the configuration object.
DataSource pool = new HikariDataSource(config);


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run
```

If you are concerned about the security of the connection you can always choose to connect to the CloudSQL proxy, using the [JDBC socket factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory). Please note that in this situation your JDBC URL should look like this :

```
jdbc:mysql:///<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&user=<MYSQL_USER_NAME>&password=<MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD>
```

Try to connect using the full URL and review it a few times. I've see this identical error when people did a little mistake in the JDBC Url, like an extra semicolon, colon etc..

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my original question based on your comments

Comment: I've noticed that you use the base URL string. Could you, please, replace it with the full JDBC URL String that is in my answer, with the all the parameters mentioned and see if there is any difference ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Cloud SQL private IP with Cloud Run, it's not yet compliant, you can forgot this way. Read replica will change nothing, you can also save money and delete it!

First, allow you Cloud SQL database to be reached by 0.0.0.0/0 network. Like this, you can validate that your Cloud Run container work correctly with a database open to internet.

Then, delete this configuration and retry to follow this [page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run) for connecting your MySQL instance to Cloud Run as you did. In your application, you also have to add a dependency (maven or gradle) for getting the socket factory jar.

It should work. Share more code or configuration for being able to help you more!

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my original question based on your comments

Answer (score 0):

2 years later, and I think perhaps conditions have changed. I was able to do this on Google App Engine, using the beta_settings configuration option in the app.yaml definition file.

For example

```yaml
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: 
    - <Project><Zone><Metabase_backend_postgresql_instance>=tcp:5432
    - <Same Project><Same Zone><Some MySql cloud instance>=tcp:3306
```

When adding the database connection in the Metabase UI, the IP address needs to be set to 127.17.0.1 per [Google documentation on the flex environment](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#connecting_to).